# Files not displaying in browser using a multi-threaded python server socket

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

The problem I'm running into is as follows:

I've built a multi-threaded TCP server using the socket module in Python (or at least, I've tried to). The server worked just fine in its single-threaded implementation, and seems to send the file just fine through the CLI when I'm using it with a client script that I've written, but when I use it with a browser, the files simply don't show up - the HTTP status message will come through (HTTP/1.0 200 OK or HTTP/1.0 404 File Not Found), but the file itself will not... or if it does, it doesn't show up in the browser.

If someone could take a look at my code and help me figure out what's going on, I would be very appreciative. Here is the main part of my code (I've omitted the import statements and the if dunder-name equals dunder-main part of the code...):

```
#Thread function:

def threaded(connectionSocket):

    while True:

        try:
            #Request received from client
            message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)

            #Create received time stamp
            recv_time = time.time()

           #If the request is coming from the CLI, do this:
            filename = message

            #If the request is coming from a browser, do this:
            if len(message.decode('utf-8')) > 20:
                #Parse message from client
                filename = message.split()[1]

            filename = filename.decode('utf-8')
            f = open('.' + filename, 'r')
            outputdata = f.read(1024)

            #Send HTTP 200 OK Response message
            connectionSocket.sendall(bytes("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n", "utf-8"))

            #Send data to client
            connectionSocket.sendall(outputdata.encode('utf-8'))

            #Display response to console
            print("HTTP/1.0 200 OK")

            #Create sent time stamp
            sent_time = time.time()
            break

        except:

            #Send response message for file not found
            connectionSocket.send(bytes('HTTP/1.0 404 File Not Found \n', 'utf-8'))

            #Display to console
            print("HTTP/1.0 404 File Not Found")

            #Create time stamp
            sent_time = time.time()
            break

    #Calculate RTT
    rtt = round((sent_time - recv_time), 3)

    #Display RTT
    print("RTT: " + str(rtt) + "ms")

    #Close connection and release lock
    connectionSocket.close()
    data_lock.release()
    print("Lock Released\n")

#The serve function which generates the server socket and initiates the thread

def serve():
    #Create a server socket
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    #Prepare a server socket
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 50007
    serverSocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    serverSocket.listen(5)

    while True:

        #Acquire lock
        data_lock.acquire()
        print("Lock acquired")
        print('Ready to serve...')

        #Establish the connection
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        print('Connected by ' + str(addr))

        #Start new thread
        start_new_thread(threaded, (connectionSocket,))
        break

    #Close this socket
    serverSocket.close()

#The main function:
def Main():
    while True:
        serve()
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something rather obvious, but I'm rather new to socket programming and multi-threading and all such as that. Any advice would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you fill in the missing bits of your code (such as `start_new_thread`) so that it can run without modifications? There are many problems with your code, and you shouldn’t be writing an HTTP server this way, but if this is an exercise, then it may be possible to pinpoint which of the problems is causing the behavior you describe.

Comment: I'm surprised that this worked in the single threaded version. This is not a valid HTTP response you send there, i.e. there is no delimiter between HTTP header and body, the line end is `\n` instead of `\r\n`, no length is given but the socket does not get closed ... If I would be a browser I would refuse to deal with such garbage data.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich! That was precisely what I was missing! It had originally had \r\n in the single-threaded version, but I suppose it got lost in the transition. It's an obvious thing I was overlooking, but thanks to your eagle eye, I've fixed it and it works just fine! Fine enough for me, anyway. Thankfully this is just an academic exercise, and thank you all for your help. It is much appreciated.